# Site opens in HTTP even though I have defined HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl, wordpress, cloudflare

I have a WordPress site hosted on nginx. I am using Cloudflare reverse proxy and SSL. I have setup so site will only open in https and even if someone uses http then it will be redirected to https version. In Cloudflare the SSL setting is `Flexible`

But problem is, it is not working like that and when a user opens http version then it doesn't redirect to https.

This is the setting defined in my config file.

```
server {
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mysiteurl.com;
        return 301 https://www.mysiteurl.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/mysiteurl.com/html;
        index portal.php index.php  index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what URL you are using but my guess is that it matches the second server section of your config - which has no redirect to https. Why having two sections anyway, one with a `server_name` and one without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create page rule in Cloudflare to Always use HTTPS.

more information - https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ#h_999722138611548960019807

Comment: This doesn't fix the odd configuration in nginx though.

Comment: yeah, the first section of server is probably not needed when using Cloudflare https redirect and the second one could have server_name of the site.